# How to upload main and subreports in Jasper Server?

Tags: jasper-reports, jasperserver

How to upload main and subreports in Jasper Server (face linking error)?

Comment: What is the "linking error"? What do you do to get this? Are you using the web interface or the API? What tool are you using to build your reports? Does this problem affect all reports or just the one you are using? More detail, please.

Comment: i have created main reports and subreports in my local machine,and i am uploading on jasperserver but that is not working.
what is the changes when uploading main and subreports in jasperserver.

Comment: Are you uploading your reports through jasper studio or ireport? Can you just brief your question with the error message you got?

Answer (score 0):

Check this:

1. Report connection property defined, from main report to sub report done correctly.
2. Check sub report expression.
3. Linking error might be because of local to server connection. Check the connection properties.
4. Uploading the reports to server, define connection property, update the local report to the server.

If you want to move reports between report servers, you can use export import commands in jasper server-side.